# How to have multiple refenrences for a string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Please check the below code, where I am creating multiple reference for an array

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *array2 = array1;
[array1 addObject:@"One"];
[array1 addObject:@"Two"];

NSLog (@"Array1 %@",array1);
NSLog (@"Array2 %@",array2);
```

> Console output is
>
> Array1 (
>       One,
>       Two ) Array2 (
>       One,
>       Two )

Both Array1 and Array2 reference to same address

Like wise I tried for NSMutableString, I didn't work out

```
NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *str2 = str1;
str1 = @"Hello";

NSLog (@"Str1 : %@", str1);
NSLog (@"Str2 : %@", str2);
```

> Console Output is  Str1 Hello Str2 (null)

Is there any way to have reference to string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is quite normal. With :

```
str1 = @"Hello";
```

`str1` doesn't point to the memory you allocated two lines above anymore. `str2` didn't change and still point to that memory place.

The example you gave doesn't looks the same for arrays and string. In the first you *add* objects to one array, but don't change the value of any pointer.

In the second you are modifiying the *reference* to an object.

The second example, should be written as something like :

```
NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *str2 = str1;
[str1 appendString:@"foo"];

NSLog (@"Str1 : %@", str1);
NSLog (@"Str2 : %@", str2);
```

Output :

> Str1 : foo
>   Str2 : foo

Given two *references* on the same mutable string (one memory place), and using `NSMutableString`'s method, both references will be modified.

Comment: My requirement is to have str1 and str2 point to same memory, when I change string in any of the one ,should update the both

Comment: that is what the code I wrote is supposed to do. see updated answer